# Constructing a regex to interpret a user's order of a fixed format for a system

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create an order book system and am stuck in trying to create the correct regex for it. The user can enter an order in the format of `order ID | side | amount | price` or cancel an order in the format of `cancel | order ID` where 'cancel' is a keyword. ID can be any reasonable number of alphanumeric characters.

Examples of **correct** input:

- `aa buy 10 10`
- `bb buy 2 9`
- `cc sell 11 10`
- `cancel aa`
- `sadkjdscxf buy 30 20`

Examples of **incorrect** input

- `cancel aa aabc`
- `asdfhdsajhfdsa`
- `aa buys 10 10`
- `aa buy 12 10 2`
- `aa buy 12a 10`
- `aa bsell 5 1`

I've managed to create a regex to detect cancel orders, namely `^(cancel\\s)(\\w+)$`, but how can I incorporate this into the regular order statements as well?

Comment: Do you want to use a single regex for `cancel` and normal orders? See [`^(?:cancel\s+[^\W_]+|[^\W_]+\s+buy\s+\d+\s+\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/9sfVBr/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following class shows how to use a RegExp for that:

```
public class RegExpOrders {

    private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((cancel)\\s+(\\w+))|((\\w+)\\s+(buy|sell)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+))$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final RegExpOrders regExpOrders = new RegExpOrders();

        System.out.println("should be ok:");
        regExpOrders.check("aa buy 10 10");
        regExpOrders.check("bb buy 2 9");
        regExpOrders.check("cc sell 11 10");
        regExpOrders.check("cancel aa");
        regExpOrders.check("sadkjdscxf buy 30 20");

        System.out.println("should not be ok:");
        regExpOrders.check("cancel aa aabc");
        regExpOrders.check("asdfhdsajhfdsa");
        regExpOrders.check("aa buys 10 10");
        regExpOrders.check("aa buy 12 10 2");
        regExpOrders.check("aa buy 12a 10");
        regExpOrders.check("aa bsell 5 1");
    }

    private void check(String s) {
        final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);

        final boolean result = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println("checking (" + s + "): " + result);
        if (result) {
            // group 0 is the whole pattern
            // group 1 the cancel or buy/sell part

            if ("cancel".equals(matcher.group(2))) {
                System.out.println("  cancel order");
                System.out.println("    order-id: " + matcher.group(3));
            } else {
                System.out.println("  exec order");
                System.out.println("    order id: " + matcher.group(5));
                System.out.println("    action: " + matcher.group(6));
                System.out.println("    amount: " + matcher.group(7));
                System.out.println("    price: " + matcher.group(8));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The RegExp is basically a combination of two different parts, which are combined with `|` and grouped in parentheses.

The first part is `(cancel)\\s+(\\w+))` which is the *cancel* keyword followed by at least one space followed by at least one word character. I put each relevant component on parentheses to be able to get their values from the  matcher.

The second part is `((\\w+)\\s+(buy|sell)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)`. This is a word, followed by spacem followed by either *buy* or *sell*, followed by space, followed by number, followed by space, followed by a number.

As I have the relevant parts put in parentheses, I can after the match get the values from the `Matcher` object and print them.

Comment: Thank you sir this works marvellously! May I suggest that you add a `$` to the end of the cancel statement so it becomes `((cancel)\\s+(\\w+)$)` because otherwise the cancel scenario which is supposed to fail, doesn't.

Comment: running the program shows: `checking (cancel aa aabc): false`, so the cancel fails as it should

Comment: I checked on regex101 and it seems to process the string fine. Maybe it's just different flavours of regex?

Comment: shouldn't be, which java version do you use?